# Fetch Foursquare venue data

Tags: api, foursquare

Does Foursquare provide any enterprise level plan/paid plans for developers?

Comment: Your question is not about programming and off-topic SO, you should contact and ask them

Comment: There is one way to contact them and that is through StackOverFlow.

Answer (score 0):

You can contact the enterprise team at [enterprise.foursquare.com](https://enterprise.foursquare.com/)